# ¿Cómo consigo los datos de varios input que autocomplete a otro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito rellenar una línea de un `input` con otros valores que antes he dado y si puede ser separados por guiones.

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Titulo del Documento</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="titulo_documento" id="titulo_documento" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('titulo_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Compañia</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="compania" id="compania" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo del proyecto</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="codigo_proyecto" readonly id="codigo_proyecto" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tengo esto, pero sólo me recoge un dato de los dos

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#titulo_documento').change(function() {
    $('#codigo_proyecto, #compania').val(
      $(this).val()
    );
  });
});
```

Lo que quiero es que lo de dos campos me lo inserte en uno.

Vale decir: titulo_documento+compania se deben de insertar en codigo_proyecto cada vez que haya una modificación de este mismo.

Comment: Está poco claro. ¿qué 2 campos y en qué otro campo? ¿sería poner en `#titulo_documento` el valor de `#codigo_proyecto` un guión y el valor de `#compania`? ¿y en qué momento debería suceder, con qué evento?

Comment: Por otro lado, cuando se realiza una pregunta de JavaScript, conviene publicar el HTML ya renderizado, evitando que esté el código de PHP que pueda confundir. La idea es que generes un [mcve]. ¿Podrás [edit] la pregunta para aclararlo?

Comment: en vez de editar la pregunta, si te interesa mostrar el código final, podrías publicar una **respuesta** (es el formato que seguimos en el sitio: pregunta arriba, respuestas bajo). Asimismo, no olvides aceptar la respuesta que solucionó tu problema, haciendo click en el ✔️ a la izquierda de la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Cual es el problema de repetir la funcionalidad?
Prueba con esto.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#titulo_documento, #compania').change(function() {
    $('#codigo_proyecto').val($('#titulo_documento').val() + $('#compania').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Titulo del Documento</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="titulo_documento" id="titulo_documento" value="" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Compañia</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="compania" id="compania" value="" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo del proyecto</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="codigo_proyecto" readonly id="codigo_proyecto" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pero eso lo que me hace es que lo que pongo en el campo titulo_documento me lo inserta en dos campos, y eso no es lo que quiero, lo que queiro es que lo de dos campos me lo inserte en uno

Comment: te refieres a codigo_proyecto + titulo_documento se inserte en compañia? Que campos, que orden y a que campo. Si me defines eso, pues sera sencillo poder ayudarte :D

Comment: exacto, titulo_documento+compañia se deben de insertar en codigo_proyecto por ejemplo al tabular de un campoa  otro

Comment: Edite la respuesta. Cada vez que se cambie #titulo_documento o #compania, este cambiara la concatenación de #codigo_proyecto. Según lo que entendí que necesitabas. Exito :D

Comment: Muchisimas gracias funciona a la perfeccion inyecto codigo nuevo por si alguien lo quiere que se vaya separando con guiones a su vez tambien.

Comment: Me alegro poder haberte ayudado. Éxito con tu proyecto! :D